# When talking about AngularJS, what exactly is the view?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, view

When talking about AngularJS, what exactly is the view? Or can it be more than one thing?

Comment: `HTML` page. Anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**View is what the user sees (the DOM).**

> Normal HTML in Angular is called template. When Angular starts your
>   application, it parses and processes the markup from the template
>   using the compiler. The loaded, transformed and rendered DOM is then
>   called the view.

Have a look at the following image:

[image]

Source: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts#view

Answer (score 0):

**All your HTML pages are the view.** JS files are usually controllers or services.

HTML is the user interface (the view) and JavaScript is the engine of the application, consists mainly of controllers and services (see [Angular's service as a model](http://rob.conery.io/2013/04/25/models-and-services-in-angular/)).

[image]

**So, the view is all the user could see.**

Comment: Khalid's answer conflicts with yours. Would you like to expand?

Comment: I don't see the conflict, please specify.